# How do I get my total by adding all my subtotals?

Tags: c++

I have my program doing 90% of what I want all that is left to do is get the total by adding all my subtotals and outputting to a file. It my be something simple but I can't seem to find a way to get the total of all my subtotals added together. To be honest, even though I need to make it output into a text file I have not attempted anything yet because I was trying to figure a way to get my total. Would someone mind finding me a solution and explaining it so I get a better understanding.

```
//Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream theFile("input.txt");

    string name;
    int units;
    double price, subtotal;

    cout << "\n" <<string(80, '*') << endl;
    cout.width(66); cout << "Inventory Report For Jane Doe International Hardware" << endl;
    cout << string(80, '*') << "\n" << endl;

    cout << left << setw(20) << "ITEM";
    cout << right << setw(20) << "NUMBER OF UNITS";
    cout << right << setw(20) << "UNIT COST ($)";
    cout << right << setw(20) << "TOTAL VALUE ($)" << endl;
    cout << string(80, '-') << "\n" <<endl;

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);

    while (theFile >> name >> units >> price) {
        subtotal = units*price;
        cout << left << setw(20) << name << right << setw(15) << units << right << setw(20) << price << right << setw(20) << subtotal <<endl;
    }

    cout << "\n" <<string(80, '-') << endl;
    cout <<left << setw(20) << "Inventory Total ($)" << right << setw(55) << "total" <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My input text file

```
Chisel 50 9.99  Hammer 30 15.99 Nails 2000 0.99
Bolts 200 2.99  Nuts 300 1.99   Soap 55 1.89
```

Comment: Just simply add the subtotals... I am wondering, what is so difficult?

Comment: I'm not to sure how since I have it in a while loop so my subtotal variable is constantly changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sum up all subtotals. However, each subtotal is only accessible in its iteration, afterwards, it's lost since you reassign subtotal.

Hence, declare a variable `total` outside of your while loop, then add the subtotal to the total in each iteration. Thus, add the following line

```
subtotal = units*price;
total += subtotal;
```

Now you can print `total` later on.